# Isotope URL Hash not working when called on page load

Tags: jquery, joomla, jquery-isotope

I've got an issue with Isotope where I've switched to the URL Hash method of filtering because I need to be able to send visitors to the page with a filter already active.

When I use the filter normally - i.e. page load is unfiltered and clicking a button activates a filter, everything works as expected.

When arriving from another page with the hash in the URL, it does activate the filtering, but it doesn't properly hide the remaining items - instead they're all bunched up at 0,0 absolute and not hidden. Only the filtered items are laid out properly, like so (properly filtered items have been blurred for a level of privacy):

[image]

This is the code I already have:

```js
<script>
(function( $ ){
 
 
 function getHashFilter() {
  var hash = location.hash;
  // get filter=filterName
  var matches = location.hash.match( /filter=([^&]+)/i );
  var hashFilter = matches && matches[1];
  return hashFilter && decodeURIComponent( hashFilter );
 }
 
 
 $( function() {

  var $container = $('.blogGrid');

  // bind filter button click
  var $filters = $('.filter-button-group').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
   var filterAttr = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
   // set filter in hash
   location.hash = 'filter=' + encodeURIComponent( filterAttr );
  });
  
  var isIsotopeInit = false;
  
  function onHashchange() {
   var hashFilter = getHashFilter();
   if ( !hashFilter && isIsotopeInit ) {
    return;
   }
   isIsotopeInit = true;
   // filter isotope
   $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.blogItem',
    percentPosition: true,
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    filter: hashFilter
   });
   // set selected class on button
   if ( hashFilter ) {
    $filters.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
    $filters.find('[data-filter="' + hashFilter + '"]').addClass('is-checked');
   }
  }
  
  $(window).on( 'hashchange', onHashchange );
  // trigger event handler to init Isotope
  onHashchange();
 });
 
})( jQuery );
</script>
```

I'm in Joomla, so I also have the ability to send variables by user session - but I couldn't see an Isotope method that would work that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the filtering was occurring before layout was complete, so there was no final arranging of filtered items.

I just added

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $container.isotope();
});
```

To the bottom of the script to trigger a re-arrangement after the document finished loading.

That seems to have sorted it.